# I'm trying to figure out a way to create multiple columns from values that have a sequence in R

Tags: r

For example, i want to split up the "1-5" to be "1,2,3,4,5" but have values in their own column.

```
| patient | Tooth |
|---------| ------|
|qw| 1-5|
|lo| 4-5|
|wq| 15|
|fg| 16:24|
```

The table that i want

```
| patient | Tooth | Col1| Col2|
|---------| ------| ----| ----|
|qw| 1-5| 1 |2|
|lo| 4-5| 4 | 5|
|wq| 15| 15 | 
|fg| 16:24| 16 | 17
```

Comment: I've added code formatting to what you had in your question, but your desired output doesn't make any sense to me. Is it complete?

Answer (score 0):

I'd converted "1-5" to "1:5" with gsub, the latter which can be evaluated as a R legal sequence. This was then added in as a compiled column in the data frame (as Tooth 2) and was separated into columns with dplyr::separate.

```
df <- read.table(text="patient  Tooth
qw  1-5
lo  4-5
wq  15
fg  16:24", header=TRUE)

df$Tooth <- gsub("-", ":", df$Tooth)
df$Tooth2 <- sapply(df$Tooth, function(x) paste(eval(parse(text=x)), collapse="_"))

library(dplyr)
df %>% separate(Tooth2, into=paste0("Col", 1:9), sep="_")

  patient Tooth Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9
1      qw   1:5    1    2    3    4    5 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2      lo   4:5    4    5 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3      wq    15   15 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
4      fg 16:24   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24
```

Comment: Thanks for helping @Adam! I had a feeling if I replaced "-" with ":" I could work something out but wasnt sure how to start! Would this also work with letters? Like "a:f" for example?

Comment: Nope, because `a:f` is not a valid R expression. You can probably do something like `rawToChar(as.raw(seq(as.numeric(charToRaw("a")),as.numeric(charToRaw("f")))))` to get the sequence.